# Work with Chinese in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, encoding

I`m trying to work with Chinese text and big data in Python.
Part of work is clean text from some unneeded data. For this goal I am using regexes. However I met some problems as in Python regex as in PyCharm application:

1) The data is stored in postgresql and viewed well in the columns, however, after select and  pull it to the var it is displayed as a square:

[image]
When the value printed to the console is looks like:

Mentholatum 曼秀雷敦 男士 深层活炭洁面乳100g（新包装）

So I presume there is no problem with application encoding but with debug part of encoding, however, I did not find any solutions for such behaviour.

2) The example of regex that I need to care is to remove the values between Chinese brackets include them. The code I used is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

import re
from pprint import pprint 
import sys, locale, os

    columnString = row[columnName]
    startFrom = valuestoremove["startsTo"]
    endWith = valuestoremove["endsAt"]
    isInclude = valuestoremove["include"]
    escapeCharsRegex = re.compile('([\.\^\$\*\+\?\(\)\[\{\|])')
    nonASCIIregex = re.compile('([^\x00-\x7F])')
    if escapeCharsRegex.match(startFrom):
        startFrom = re.escape(startFrom)
    if escapeCharsRegex.match(endWith):
        endWith = re.escape(endWith)

    if isInclude:
        regex = startFrom + '(.*)' + endWith
    else:
        regex = '(?<=' + startFrom + ').*?(?=' + endWith + ')'
    if nonASCIIregex.match(regex):
        p = re.compile(ur'' + regex)
    else:
        p = re.compile(regex)
    row[columnName] = p.sub("", columnString).strip()
```

But the regex does not influence on the given string.
I`ve made  a test with next code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import re

reg = re.compile(ur'（(.*)）')
string = u"巴黎欧莱雅 男士 劲能冰爽洁面啫哩（原男士劲能净爽洁面啫哩）100ml"
print string
string = reg.sub("", string)
print string
```

And it is work fine for me.
The only difference between those two code examples is that n the first the regex values are come from the txt file with json, encoded as utf-8:

```
{
                "between": {
                    "startsTo": "(",
                    "endsAt": "）",
                    "include": true,
                    "sequenceID": "1"
                }
            }, {
                "between": {
                    "startsTo": "（",
                    "endsAt": ")",
                    "include": true,
                    "sequenceID": "2"
                }
            },{
                "between": {
                    "startsTo": "(",
                    "endsAt": ")",
                    "include": true,
                    "sequenceID": "2"
                }
            },{
                "between": {
                    "startsTo": "（",
                    "endsAt": "）",
                    "include": true,
                    "sequenceID": "2"
                }
            }
```

The Chinese brackets from the file are also viewed like the squares:

[image]

I cant find explanation or any solution for such behavior, thus the community help need

Thanks for help.

Comment: square is normally because of font settings, in application or in OS.

Comment: How are you reading in the file?

Comment: @PatrickCollins
`try:
    '''with open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wisher\Cleaner_Json_CD_Vinils.txt", "r") as myfile:'''
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as myfile:
        data_file = myfile.read()
        data = lambda: None
        data.__dict__ = json.loads(data_file)
except Exception as ex:
    print ex.message`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the text you're reading in isn't getting understood as Unicode correctly (this is one of the big gotchas that prompted sweeping changes for Python 3k). Instead of:

```
data_file = myfile.read()
```

You need to tell it to decode the file:

```
data_file = myfile.read().decode("utf8")
```

Then continue with `json.loads`, etc, and it should work out fine. Alternatively,

```
data = json.load(myfile, "utf8")
```

Comment: Thanks,  I will try this and give you a feedback if this will work for me

Comment: Thanks Patrick, you answer give us a feedback for our solution. Please see my answer below

Comment: Not exactly... It works for the only Chinese text\string case, but for the mix content, with numbers or with other languages it is not works properly. But you view of solution led us to answer above. May be you could help us with another problem that we faced with. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195919/python-ufffd-after-replacement-with-chinese-content. The given solution does not helps with mix content that I talked above.

Answer (score 0):

After many searches and consultations here is a solution for Chinese text (also mixed and non-mixed language)

```
import codecs
def betweencase(valuestoremove, row, columnName):
    columnString = row[columnName]
    startFrom = valuestoremove["startsTo"]
    endWith = valuestoremove["endsAt"]
    isInclude = valuestoremove["include"]
    escapeCharsRegex = re.compile('([\.\^\$\*\+\?\(\)\[\{\|])')
    if escapeCharsRegex.match(startFrom):
        startFrom = re.escape(startFrom)
    if escapeCharsRegex.match(endWith):
        endWith = re.escape(endWith)
    if isInclude:
        regex = ur'' + startFrom + '(.*)' + endWith
    else:
        regex = ur'(?<=' + startFrom + ').*?(?=' + endWith + ')'

    ***p = re.compile(codecs.encode(unicode(regex), "utf-8"))***
    delimiter = ' '
    if localization == 'CN':
        delimiter = ''

    row[columnName] = p.sub(delimiter, columnString).strip()
```

As you can see we encode any regex to utf-8 thus the postgresql db value is match to regex.