# Python \ufffd after replacement with Chinese content

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

After we found the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138392/work-with-chinese-in-python) we are faced with next unusual replacement behavior:

Our regex is:

```
[\\(（\\[{【]+(\\w+|\\s+|\\S+|\\W+)?[）\\)\\]}】]+
```

We are trying to match all content inside any type of brackets including the brackets
The original text is:

```
物理化学名校考研真题详解 (理工科考研辅导系列(化学生物类))
```

The result is:

```
物�研真题详解
```

The code for the replacement is:

```
 delimiter = ' '
 if localization == 'CN':
        delimiter = ''
  p = re.compile(codecs.encode(unicode(regex), "utf-8"), flags=re.I)
  columnString = (p.sub(delimiter, columnString).strip()
```

Why � ( \ufffd) character appear and how to fix such behavior?

Same problem we are faced when we used regex:

```
(\\d*[满|元])

print repr(columnString)='\xe5\xbd\x93\xe4\xbb\xa3\xe9\xaa\xa8\xe4\xbc\xa4\xe7\xa7\x91\xe5\xa6\x99\xe6\x96\xb9(\xe7\xac\xac\xe5\x9b\x9b\xe7\x89\x88)'

print repr(regex)=u'[\\(\uff08\\[{\u3010]+(\\w+|\\s+|\\S+|\\W+)?[\uff09\\)\\]}\u3011]+'

print repr(p.pattern)='[\\(\xef\xbc\x88\\[{\xe3\x80\x90]+(\\w+|\\s+|\\S+|\\W+)?[\xef\xbc\x89\\)\\]}\xe3\x80\x91]+'
```

Comment: Why are you using an encoded UTF-8 regex, and not use a Unicode regular expression?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not understand clearly your question but I read the regex from file with utf-8 encoding

Comment: Can you please show us the output of `print repr(columnString)` and `print repr(regex)` too please?

Comment: And how did you manage to make `unicode()` work on the `regex` bytestring? On a normal Python 2.7 installation, that'll throw a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception, because `unicode()` will try and decode the value as ASCII.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry wrong paste from console... updated above

Comment: I meant that `unicode(regex)` will fail because there are non-ASCII bytes in your `regex` string. The only way to make that work is to call `sys.setdefaultencoding()`, which requires re-enabling that method and is a big mistake; don't ever do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix UTF-8 and regular expressions. Process all your text as Unicode. Make sure you *decoded* both the regex and the input string to `unicode` values first:

```
>>> import re
>>> columnString = '\xe5\xbd\x93\xe4\xbb\xa3\xe9\xaa\xa8\xe4\xbc\xa4\xe7\xa7\x91\xe5\xa6\x99\xe6\x96\xb9(\xe7\xac\xac\xe5\x9b\x9b\xe7\x89\x88)'
>>> regex = '[\\(\xef\xbc\x88\\[{\xe3\x80\x90]+(\\w+|\\s+|\\S+|\\W+)?[\xef\xbc\x89\\)\\]}\xe3\x80\x91]+'
>>> utf8_compiled = re.compile(regex, flags=re.I)
>>> utf8_compiled.sub('', columnString)
'\xe5\xbd\x93\xe4\xbb\xa3\xe9\xaa\xa8\xe4'
>>> print utf8_compiled.sub('', columnString).decode('utf8', 'replace')
当代骨�
>>> unicode_compiled = re.compile(regex.decode('utf8'), flags=re.I | re.U)
>>> unicode_compiled.sub('', columnString.decode('utf8'))
u'\u5f53\u4ee3\u9aa8\u4f24\u79d1\u5999\u65b9'
>>> print unicode_compiled.sub('', columnString.decode('utf8'))
当代骨伤科妙方
>>> print unicode_compiled.sub('', u'物理化学名校考研真题详解 (理工科考研辅导系列(化学生物类))')
物理化学名校考研真题详解
```

When using UTF-8 in your pattern consists of *separate bytes* for the `【` codepoint:

```
>>> '【'
'\xe3\x80\x90'
```

which means your character class matches any of those bytes; `\xe3`, or `\x80` or `\x90` are *each separately* valid bytes in that character class.

Comment: I check you solution with mixed content strings and texts i.e. Chinese and English and digits and it is not working with them., but thanks for you feedback for our problem

Comment: @Alex it certainly works with the given values from your question and caused by matching individual UTF-8 bytes rather than unicode codepoints. You may well have additional problems to solve however. Your use of `codecs.encode()` over the `unicode.encode()` method is unconventional for example.

Answer (score 0):

Decode your string first , and you can get rid of that  � ( \ufffd) character .

```
In [1]: import re
   ...: subject = '物理化学名校考研真题详解 (理工科考研辅导系列(化学生物类))'.decode('utf-8')
   ...: reobj = re.compile(r"[\(（\[{【]+(\w+|\s+|\S+|\W+)?[）\)\]}】]+", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
   ...: result = reobj.sub("", subject)
   ...: print result
   ...: 
物理化学名校考研真题详解
```